# Случайные символы из массива в строку, с сохранением символов

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Есть массив, состоящий из англ букв, цифр, и др символов.
нужно выбрать из массива х рандомных элементов и сделать из них строку СИМВОЛОВ.
Суть проблемы в том что при implode http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php элементы собираються в строку НО все они преобразовываються в числа.

Есть др способ: в цилке по 1 эл массива лепить к строке - так работало и работает, но я хочу по другому сделать (по научному :))

Может кой-то (?) параметр указать, или еще что-то и оно в одной строчке кода склеит нужную строку.

есть масиив:

```
function genpsw() {
$mass = array(

    '(',
    ')',
    '-',
    '=',
    '_',
    '+',
    '0',
    '1',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
...

 ...
...
    'w',
    'x',
    'y',
    'z');

//рабочий код

$x = 0; //
$psw = '';
shuffle($mass);//1 раз перемішати масив
while ($x < 16) {
$z = array_rand($mass);
$psw = "$psw$mass[$z]";
$x++;
}
return ($psw);
}
```

Нужно заменить этот цикл на код попроще. Я использовал implode(), но implode() почему то при сборке строки возвращает не значения элементов массива, а ключи  массива.

```
shuffle($mass);//массив тот же
$psw=array_rand($mass,16);

$psw=implode('', $psw);//$psw - это строка которая содержит КЛЮЧИ массива
```

А мне нужно чтобы там были значения ключей

Comment: А вы покажите код, где такая финтифлюха происходит и можно будет сказать, что там не так

Comment: уже решил. . Хоть в документации написано "Возвращает строку, содержащую строковое представление всех элементов массива в указанном порядке, со строкой glue между каждым элементом...."

Comment: Может поделитесь решением? А также в сам вопрос добавите код? Иначе на закрытие

Comment: код...? код в коментариях не удобно писать. Может в ответе дописать? ааа понял. ссейчас

Comment: Ну так править вопрос вам никто не запрещает (есть такая ссылочка "править")

Comment: уже корректно(?) все сделал.

Comment: Итого.... проблема у вас в `array_rand` а не `implode`..... ибо  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php ...... Выбирает одно или несколько случайных значений из массива. Возвращает **ключ (или ключи)** данных случайных элементов.

Comment: ну, да на этапе отладки я это видел http://itmages.ru/image/view/4311417/79bf2036 Зря я на implode грешил. Но в итоге цикл заменил на одну строку кода. Что и нужно было.

Comment: Ну дык......это вроде как должно было и насторожить......и вот поэтому важно в вопрос добавлять код))........предлагаю из ответа убрать ваше неверное предположение об `implode` и указать именно эту причину проблемы, а также указать что делает  `array_slice` с сылкой на доки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что я использовал `implode()`, **после выбора случайных элементов массива** при помощи `array_rand()`.
А функция [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php) возвращает рандомный ключ (или ключи), а не значения, как задумывалось

Как решение было задумано использовать [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)

Функция `array_slice()` выбирает срез массива. Она может производить выбор с конца массива, если указано отрицательное смещение.

Решение:

```
shuffle($mass);
$passwd = implode('', array_slice($mass, 0, 16));
```

В данном коде выражение

```
array_slice($mass, 0, 16)
```

выбирает 16 элементов массива, начиная со смешения 0 (с начала массива). 
И далее склеивает элементы массива в строку при помощи `implode()`

В итоге цикл заменил на одну строку кода, что и было нужно.

Comment: укажите мне где в документации об этом написано? Может нужно оригинал документации смотреть, а не ее перевод. Я выше подправил вопрос. Я чего-то в жизни не понимаю? :)

Comment: больше не удаляйте ответ)) Ответ должен быть в ответе. В вопросе не надо размещать решение)

Comment: понял.  О том что именно я ПОНЯЛ не буду писать, потому что я ПОНЯЛ. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function genpsw() {
$mass = array(

    '(',
    ')',
    '-',
    '=',
    '_',
    '+',
    '0',
    '1',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'w',
    'x',
    'y',
    'z');

//рабочий код

shuffle($mass);//1 раз перемішати масив
$psw=array_rand($mass,16);

    $tmp = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($psw); $i++) {
        $tmp .= $mass[$psw[$i]];
    }


    return $tmp;
}


print(genpsw());
```

Comment: неет.  Задача (вопрос) еще и о том как сделать это БЕЗ циклов. Ваш пример такой же как и мой, но у меня цикл while{}. НО..., сколько людей, столько и мыслЕй ;)